# What is the best practice to zip the build results, by build scripts or build tools?

Tags: build, devops

I'm writing my only build scripts and setup jenkins, Jenkins provide plugins to zip the build results, meanwhile I can zip the result in my own build scripts and call that scripts from Jenkins. Which way is better?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a corporate environment where a number of teams share the same Jenkins master, each plugin you add increases the probability of a plugin failure as and when you upgrade Jenkins. In addition, a bad plugin can bring down your entire CI server. So, in a common master scenario, be very conservative on adding plugins, don't add a plugin unless it is absolutely necessary. For something as simple as creating zips, any build tool worth its salt has a task that can zip contents in a given folder. Read through Maven and Gradle for a start.